# How to open products in new tabs when using product Shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have used following shortcodes in the Home page to display set of products :-

```
[products limit="15"  orderby="menu_order"  columns="5"  category="shirt, shoe"]
```

However when any product image is clicked on the Home page, the specific link is opened on the same tab. I would like to open that link in a separate tab. How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Note: I am using Oceanwp as my active theme

Answer (score 1):

Funny, i just had the same issue few days ago. Here's how i've solved it:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open' ) ) {
    /**
     * Insert the opening anchor tag for products in the loop.
     */
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
        global $product;
        
        $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );
        
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($link) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link" target="_blank">';
    }
}
```

Tested and works. You can just paste this into your functions.php or if you've made a custom plugin just include this at the very beginning.

You might need to add "[is_home()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/)" or "[is_front_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)" to make it hit just the home page and not the whole site

Comment: Thanks. So far this change doesn't work for me. I found that above function is already defined in "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php". Although the last line don't have {target="_blank"} section.  Also I don't see the corresponding do_filter() call in the codebase. Is it expected ?

Comment: I have observed that from the file 
 "themes/oceanwp/inc/woocommerce/woocommerce-config.php" the following function is called := remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 ).  Probably this is the reason it is not working for me.

Comment: Well yeah, if you found that your theme is removing the 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' action then of course the code won't work. That was meant to work in a normal situation. You should then look what your theme is doing to print the link tag for the product and then we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using Oceanwp theme, I have to modify in different places than what is suggested by @Diego. But his answer gives me the clue for finding the solution.
This is the modification  I did to make it work for Oceanwp.

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'ocean_woo_img_link_open' ) ) {
        function ocean_woo_img_link_open() {
                global $product;
                $woo_img_link = get_the_permalink( $product->get_id() );
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $woo_img_link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link" target="_blank" >';
        }
}
```